# How do I prevent Trigger recursion in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which will update the grades of all the friends of a student whose grade is updated.

```
create trigger upgrade
after update on Highschooler
when new.grade=old.grade+1 and trigger_nestlevel() < 2
begin
    update Highschooler
    set grade=new.grade
    where ID in (
      select ID2
      from Friend
       where ID1=old.ID
    )
;
end
```

friends of friends (of friends...) of the person whose grade is increased are also being 'upgraded' how can i stop this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can read in  [Limits In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) you can clear the recursive trigger capability by using the **PRAGMA recursive_triggers** statement.

> **10. Maximum Depth Of Trigger Recursion**
>
> SQLite limits the depth of recursion of triggers in order to prevent a
>   statement involving recursive triggers from using an unbounded amount
>   of memory.
>
> Prior to SQLite version 3.6.18, triggers were not recursive and so
>   this limit was meaningless. Beginning with version 3.6.18, recursive
>   triggers were supported but had to be explicitly enabled using the
>   [PRAGMA recursive_triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers) statement. Beginning with version 3.7.0,
>   recursive triggers are enabled by default but can be manually disabled
>   using [PRAGMA recursive_triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers). The SQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH is only
>   meaningful if recursive triggers are enabled.
>
> The default maximum trigger recursion depth is 1000.