# How to execute a trigger multiple times in SQLite android?

Tags: android, triggers, android-sqlite, android-database

I am developing an android application that has implementation of SQLite database, i want to create a trigger that runs a number of times utill specificcount is reached.

**What is required**

There are 2 tables TABLE 1 and TABLE 2

- After insert on TABLE 1 a trigger should be called 12 times and
  insert 12 rows in TABLE 2 based on specific WHERE CLAUSE
- On 13th time
  trigger should not insert any new row.

**What i tried**

> onOpen function in DatabaseHelper class

```
 @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // Enable foreign key constraints
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;\n");
        }
    }
```

> onCreate function in DatabaseHelper class

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        createTables(db);
         db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER multi_insertion AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1 \n" +
                    " WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) from TABLE2 where MYNUMBER=1) < 12\n" +
                    "  BEGIN\n " +
                    "          insert into SCHEDULE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) values ('001','002');  \n   " +
                    "  END;");
    }
```

*OUTPUT: It inserted only 1 row in TABLE 2*

Can somebody please help me out to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is not that your triggers are wrong in theory BUT that you have 3 tables:-

- TABLE1,
- TABLE2 and
- BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE

and you are getting the row count from TABLE2 but inserting into BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE.

- This answer is based upon 12 inserts into table 1 triggering 12 times, rather the interpreting *After insert on TABLE 1 a trigger should be called 12 times and insert 12 rows* as meaning that 12 rows should be inserted when the first row in table1 is inserted, if this is the requirement then you could :-

  - either use a single INSERT with mutlitple sets of values e.g. `INSERT INTO BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE (column1,column2) VALUES('001','002'),('003','004') ......`
  - or use 12 INSERT statements/actions within the BEGIN .... END construct (the given example shows such  multiple (2) statements/actions)

At a guess you need to do something like :-

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    createTables(db);
     db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER multi_insertion AFTER INSERT ON TABLE1 " +
                " WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) from TABLE2 where MYNUMBER=1) < 12" +
                " BEGIN " +
                " INSERT into BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) VALUES ('001','002');" +
                " INSERT into TABLE2 VALUES(?????????); " + //<<<<<<<<< insert a row into table 2 to act as a counter 
                "  END;");
}
```

- Obviously `??????????` should be replaced by an appropriate value or values.
- This will then add a row into table 2 and the WHEN clause will act appropriately.

  - As you can see you can have multiple ACTIONS within a TRIGGER's BEGIN .... END construct.

## Example

Consider this working example based upon what can be gleaned from your code, with an exception that table2 has had an additional column added which is used to record a value from table1 into table1, thus showing how you can use `new.`*column* within a TRIGGER.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS multi_insertion;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (mydata);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 (mynumber,valuefromtable1);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,OTHERCOLUMNS);


CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS multi_insertion
    AFTER INSERT ON table1
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) from TABLE2 where MYNUMBER=1) < 12
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,new.mydata /* record value that caused insert */); /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED TO TRIGGER >>>>>>>>>>*/
        INSERT into BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2) VALUES ('001','002');
    END;


/* Add some testing data which will exceed the 12 rows */
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('a');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('b');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('c');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('d');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('e');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('f');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('g');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('h');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('i');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('j');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('k');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('l');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('m');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('n');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('o');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('p');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('q');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES('r');

/* Results */
SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;
SELECT * FROM BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE;

/* Cleanup Text Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS multi_insertion;
```

## Results

Running the above results in :-

**Table1** i.e. with all 18 rows that were inserted.

[image]

**Table2**

[image]

- THe highlighted column shows data retreived from table 1
- as can be seen 12 rows only have been added

**BN_MS_LS_SCHEDULE**

[image]

- Likewise only 12 rows have been addded

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use triggers but you have to be careful and I'm not sure if it is a good practice to solve those kind of problems with a recursive trigger.

Your code couldn't work because you called the trigger on `TABLE1` once, which performed one **INSERT** in `TABLE2`, and that's all.

However, check the code snippet below. I added another trigger on `TABLE2` which insert the same row for 11 times.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;\n");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (NAME VARCHAR(20))");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE TABLE2 (COL1 NUMBER, COL2 NUMBER)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER multi_insertion_table1 BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE1 \n" +
                " WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) from TABLE2 where COL1=1 and COL2=2) < 12\n" +
                "  BEGIN \n" +
                "          insert into TABLE2 values (1, 2);  \n   " +
                "  END;");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER multi_insertion_table2 AFTER INSERT ON TABLE2 \n" +
                " WHEN (SELECT COUNT (*) from TABLE2 where COL1=1 and COL2=2) < 12\n" +
                "  BEGIN \n" +
                "          insert into TABLE2 values (1, 2);  \n  " +
                "  END;");
    }
```

The second trigger must be an `AFTER STATEMENT` in this case otherwise the DB will throw an exception with a message `too many levels of trigger recursion`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8374196/10048703).